# Why would I want to use a hashtable for a drop down list in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, list, hashtable

Straight from the w3schools web site,
why would I want to put these items into a hashtable?

Is this more for large amounts of data and this is just a simple demo?
Otherwise why would I spend the time to put it into a hashtable why not just put it in an array?

```
dim mycountries=New Hashtable
  mycountries.Add("N","Norway")
  mycountries.Add("S","Sweden")
  mycountries.Add("F","France")
  mycountries.Add("I","Italy")
  rb.DataSource=mycountries
  rb.DataValueField="Key"
  rb.DataTextField="Value"
  rb.DataBind()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Be aware that tags are not keywords and can not be combined to create concepts.  Tagging this question `visual` and `baisc` does not mean the same thing as tagging it with a tag that actually refers to Visual Basic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An array holds a bunch of single-valued things.

```
dim mycountries = new Collection ' My VB.Net is very rusty... hope this is right
mycountries.Add("Norway")
mycountries.Add("Sweden")
mycountries.Add("France")
mycountries.Add("Italy")
```

A Hashtable (or indeed also a Dictionary) holds a bunch of key-value pairs.

```
mycountries.Add("N","Norway")
' etc.
```

When one later enumerates a Hashtable, one gets back a `KeyValuePair<string,string>` rather than just a `string` one would get from the Collection.

This example sets the key to a short version of the value, so an array would not work (it can only hold a value).

Certainly you could use an array that holds a type that in turn has a key and a value, but using a Hashtable is more straightforward.

Comment: Should be either `dim mycountries as new collection()` or `dim mycountries as collection() = new collection()`, I think.  As written, collection would be a variant type.

Comment: thank you for answering so fast.So this is attached to a radio button control to get values to list as radio buttons.  I don't think I mentioned that before.  So why would I use a hash table vs an arraylist to populate radio buttons.  Why would I need a key value pair?

Comment: What UI technology are you using?  With HTML based forms for example, it is common to have a short code for each item in a select box.